# Undefined variable: _SESSION when sending variables via post through JavaScript trigger

Tags: php, session

In my index.php file I call `session_start()` and set a couple of session variables. In a second PHP file I would like to access these session variables.

Thing is, this PHP file is purely a backend script and is POSTed to when a JavaScript function is triggered. When the POST call attempts to cause the script in the second PHP file to be executed the error log is reporting that:

> `_SESSION` is an undefined variable.

I've tried calling `start_session()` and `session_regenerate_id()` at the top of the second PHP file but the issue has persisted.

I'm assuming what is going on is that because it's in a POST this PHP file is in its own session as I am still able to do this `$_COOKIE[ini_get('session.name')]`.

The information that I am trying to pass to the second PHP file isn't anything that needs to be secured but it would be nice to know in the future how to do this: call a PHP file via a POST and still have my session variables.

Comment: You mean `$_SESSION` right? Please post your actual code.

Comment: did you use `start_session()` or `session_start()`? If the first, then you just mixed up the commands. ;)

Comment: $_SESSION can never be undefined - it's a superglobal and is present at all times. The only time it could be undefined is if your code deleted it.

Comment: Jared -- Yes I mean't $_SESSION. That was a direct copy/paste from the error log, it does not display the dollar sign.

Lars -- Thanks for the tip but yes, I meant session_start and is what I was using.

Marc -- That is what I believed as well, and what was apparently the case as well.

Comment: Typically the actual error will have only _SESSION even when the code itself has $_SESSION

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's nothing special whatsoever about POST requests and sessions.
You just need to call `session_start` at the top of *every* <strike>file</strike> request you want to use sessions in, that's it.

Try again with that in mind, it ought to work.

Comment: You are correct, I must have done something funky because after doing it over it now works. For the curious, it was not the dollar sign, the error log simply did not display it.

Comment: This is not correct. If session_start() is called multiple times within the same execution, you could receive a warning (depending on your current warning level) : "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()".  Try if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start(); 
}

Comment: @Chris "At the top of every file" means "at the beginning of each request". Of course you don't need to do this in included files.

Comment: @deceze - I felt this was important to clarify.  Plenty of people could interpret that incorrectly.

Answer (score 8):

```
session_start();
```

is the answer of most of topic like this. i have been struggling with this issue and i solve my problem with this code

```
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
        if(session_id() == '') {session_start();}
    } else  {
       if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {session_start();}
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

you must include

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

at the beginning of your document, this will start the SESSION ENGINE and enable you to set session variables `(ie. $_SESSION['var1'], $_SESSION['var2'], etc)`

If you're wanting to get values from a $_POST you could relate the two together by :

```
$_SESSION['var1'] = $_POST['answer1']
```

Answer (score 3):

I came faced with this problem, and after trying a lot of things, I just included session_start() on the second script and it worked.

Comment: Bingo. This is the answer that helped me. The key was that I needed to put session_start(); not only in the script where I SET the session variables, but also on the page where I RECEIVE them, which is a different page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to the file browse.php:

```
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
    if(session_id() == '') {session_start();}
} else  {
   if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {session_start();}
}
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem recently. I could not access the contents of the $_SESSION variable.

1) This was as a result of trying to access the $_SESSION variable before the declaration of `session_start();` In my own case, I had already started a session in a header.php file. But I was accessing the $_SESSION variable before the include statement. Example;

```
<?php
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 //do some logical operation!!!
?> 
<?php include("header.php");?>
```

instead of doing something like this

```
<?php include("header.php");?>
<?php
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 //do some logical operation!!!
?>
```

2) Another thing that may cause this problem, maybe a failure to start a session at the top of all the files that may require access to the $_SESSION variable using

```
session_start();
```

Hope this helps anybody that stumbles on the same problem. Although this is coming at a late hour.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() is the answer. And here's one more way of going about it:

```
<?php 
if (session_id() == "") 
    session_start();    ?>
```

This will ensure that a new session is started only if you do not have a current session on already. And ofcourse, as others have said, make sure to place this at the top of the html.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried different ways and finally found a solution :

**PHP is case sensitive**, Use $_SESSION instead of $_session in all php files.certainly It works .
Example :

```
<?php
session_save_path('tmp/'); (is not optional - it is mandatory)
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["s1"]."<br/>";
echo $_SESSION["s2"]."<br/>";
?>
```