# Yii 1: Getting "undefined variable _session" on some files

Tags: php, session, yii

i am using session array in my project so i have to use 
`$_SESSION['checkToken']['quote']` this will work almost in all files. but in few files i am facing error 
`undefined variable _session`.

ex. In my TempMediaController i am facing same error when i am going to access
`echo $_SESSION['checkToken']['quote']`. but same thing works in other controllers.

For avoid this error i got one solution. on starting of TempMediaController i add `@session_start();`. This solves my problem. but i know this is not proper way. So what is proper way to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems that when action is fired, session does not autostart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is super global variable. It will be available across your application. Make sure you call `session_destroy` only in sign out function.

Comment: yes you are right but `$_SESSION` is global variable. but in few files it gives error. but i have already defined `$_SESSION['checkToken']['quote']`. and i am not destroying session before it.

Answer (score 0):

To work with session properly as you mentioned you need to call `session_start()` at the top of each script, to prevent `$_SESSION` undefined. Use [`CHttpSession`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession)  instead of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: i have to call `session_start()` on those pages in which i get `undefined session` error.

Comment: @Jazz may be this topic helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237028/undefined-variable-session-when-sending-variables-via-post-through-javascript

Comment: Did you try to use CHttpSession? @Jazz